# How to make an input field readonly

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the input field readonly. The below code is working for me. But, if the page is refreshed the input fields will become readonly and I cant enter anything in the input field. I want that to become readonly only after the data is present in the input field.

```
      const disableInputs = function() {
      sessionStorage.disableInputs = 'true';
      document.getElementById('firstname').disabled = true;
      document.getElementById('lastname').disabled = true;
      document.getElementById('email').disabled = true;
      document.getElementById('mew').disabled = true;
      };
      if (sessionStorage.disableInputs === 'true') disableInputs();
      document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = disableInputs;
```

Any help is much appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Why the *php* tag?

Comment: Removed, sorry.

Comment: onload ? or event click check to disable

Comment: why you save `disableInputs` in `sessionStorage`? seems that it should be determined when page loaded

Comment: document.getElementById("myText").readOnly = true;

Comment: Or maybe $(“#firstname”).addAttr(“disabled”); instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="someid" name="somename" readonly="readonly" value="">
```

**In PHP:**

```
 <input type="text" id="someid" name="somename" <?php if($value) { 
 echo 'readonly="readonly"'; } ?> value="<?php echo $value ?>">
```

**In Javascript:**

```
<script>
 function disableInputField() {
  if (document.getElementById("someid").value) {
    document.getElementById("someid").readOnly = true;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("someid").readOnly = false;
  }
 }
</script>
```

**All together:**

```
<input type="text" id="someid" name="somename" <?php if($value) { 
 echo 'readonly="readonly"'; } ?> value="<?php echo $value ?>" onblur="Javascript:disableInputField();">
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much for your time and answer.

Comment: If it works, plz accept the answer by click the green tick mark. This will help others who search for the same type of question.

Comment: Also, how to disable a drop-down input with the select? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `document.getElementById("your-id").readOnly = true;`

Source:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_readonly.asp

Snippet from w3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_readonly2

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myText").readOnly = true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText">

<p>Click the button to set the text field to read-only.</p>

<p><strong>Tip:</strong> To see the effect, try to type something in the text field before and after clicking the button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add readonly like required in html for eg.

Comment: He is talking about doing it from javascript. And it's a comment. Don't post it as an answer.